# git config default push destination for new branches

Tags: git, set, push, config, default

If you create a local repository by:

```
git init
```

Then how to set a default remote for `git push` so if you create a new branch and want to `git push` its commits you don't need to specify the remote destination?

Take into account that the local repository is not cloned form a remote and just initialized so it does not have any commits to be pushed nor branches.

so far I only managed to set the remote for the master because it is the default name for the first branch but this does not solve the problem because other branches that will be created have at this point unknown names.

Is there any config entry you can use to set default push destination for branches in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `push.default` to current like this:

```
git config push.default current
```

It's described in `man git-config`:

```
push.default
  Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is
  explicitly given. Different values are well-suited for
  specific workflows; for instance, in a purely central
  workflow (i.e. the fetch source is equal to the push
  destination), upstream is probably what you want. Possible
  values are:
  (...)

  current - push the current branch to update a branch with the same
  name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central
  workflows.
```

To check how it works in practice first add a remote repository you
will push to after creating a new local repository, it can even reside on the
same filesystem:

```
$ git remote add origin <REMOTE_REPO_ADDRESS>
```

and then try `git push` - first with `master` branch and then with `dev`:

```
$ touch a
$ git add a
$ git commit -minitial
[master (root-commit) c89b8e4] initial
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 206 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /tmp/git-init-remote-
 * [new branch]      master -> master
$ git checkout -b dev
Switched to a new branch 'dev'
$ touch b
$ git add b
$ git commit -mdev
$ git push
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /tmp/git-init-remote-
 * [new branch]      dev -> dev
```

Comment: Works well. Note: you need to specify the remote name as `origin`. If the name is different than `origin` then It will work but only for the master branch. All others created once you push them you'll get an error `fatal: No configured push destination.`