# git track branch by default

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-branch

By default, I would like git to always track a branch on `origin` with the same name, unless I specifically set the upstream branch to something else, for both `push` and `pull`.  But that is not the behavior I am seeing.

When I run the following:

```
$ git branch -b foo
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

But my new branch `foo` does not exist is Bitbucket unless I add the the remote and branch to the command with `git push origin foo`.  And even then, it will start tracking for `push`, but not `pull`.

```
user@host [~/git/repository] <foo> $ echo 'test' >> test.txt
user@host [~/git/repository] <foo> $ git add test.txt
user@host [~/git/repository] <foo> $ git commit -m 'test'
[foo 376b03b] test
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt
user@host [~/git/repository] <foo> $ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 277 bytes | 277.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create pull request for foo:
remote:   https://bitbucket.host.com/projects/PROJ/repos/repository/compare/commits?sourceBranch=refs/heads/foo
remote:
To ssh://bitbucket.host.com:7999/proj/repository.git
   34c6308..376b03b  foo -> foo
user@host [~/git/repository] <foo> $ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> foo

user@host [~/git/repository] <foo> $
```

I know I can set it to track for both `push` and `pull` with `git push -u origin foo`, but I'm wondering if it's possible to set some config value so that, by default, `push` will always push to the branch on `origin` with the same name, and `pull` will always pull from the branch on `origin` with the same name, so that I can just do this:

```
$ git checkout -b foo
$ #make changes
$ git commit -am 'changes'
$ git push
$ #someone else makes changes
$ git pull
```

And it will work.

Comment: A similar question but not exactly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52682174/3691891

Comment: Customizing workflows is why there are command shells and git aliases.  If you've got a sequence you do a lot, script it or if it's simple enough just make an alias for it in whatever way works best for you.  When there's thousands of people doing exactly what you're doing, then it might be time to make git supply a standard option to do it that way.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk The question may not be an exact duplicate, but I think that the answer answers this question.

Comment: Relevant to bounty I'm about to create: Can I do this for *pulls* instead of pushes. If I do a `git checkout remote_branch` then `git branch -m remote_branch new_branch` then `new_branch` pulls from origin/remote_branch.

Answer (score 3):

Use `current` as the default push strategy:

```
git config push.default current
```

Comment: This does not work for pull's.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do this for pulls instead of pushes?
> If I do a `git checkout remote_branch` then `git branch -m remote_branch new_branch` then new_branch pulls from `origin/remote_branch`?*

You still can set the `push.default` configuration to `current` to push the current branch to a branch of the same name on the origin.

```bash
git config push.default current
```

Since Git does not have a direct configuration setting like `push.default` for pull operations, you can instead make sure the tracking information is set correctly when you create a new branch or when you rename a branch.

- When you create a new branch, [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) can set the upstream branch

  ```bash
  git switch -c foo origin/foo
  ```
- When you have created a new branch, you can use the `-u` or `--set-upstream-to` flag with `git push` to set the upstream branch:

  ```bash
  git push -u origin foo
  ```
- Alternatively, after the branch has been created, you can use the `--set-upstream-to` option with `git branch` to set the tracking information:

  ```bash
  git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/foo foo
  ```

You can encapsulate the operations of creating a new branch, pushing it to the remote, and setting up tracking in a single shell function.

```bash
function git_create_and_track() {
    branch_name=$1
    git switch -c $branch_name
    git push -u origin $branch_name
}
```

Usage:

```bash
git_create_and_track foo
```

You can add this function to your shell's configuration file (e.g., `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`) to have it available in every terminal session.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I would have rewarded you the bounty by I can't for a day. `git push -u` seems the way to go as it means I don't need to do as much typing. Do I understand correctly that I can I use `git checkout -b new origin/old`; `git push -u` to make `new` track `origin/new`? It'd be cool if I could make `git push -u` the default....

Comment: @AttRigh Yes, your sequence of commands would work. And yes, there is no `git push -u` by default for now!

Comment: @AttRigh You could create a git alias `pu = push -u`, that way, `git pu new` would work.

Comment: Yeah - I'm trying to avoid too much scripting / changing my habits if possible. But that could work.